# C# to PHP decrypting

Tags: c#, php, encryption, crypt

I need to decrypt inside a PHP project some strings that were encrypted with C# in a project.

AFter some research i noticed that the C# project uses the Interop.ACECRYPTLib dll which looks like call it's a wrapper for the CRYPTLib dll... I have the password that it's used to encrypt the strings, and i see inside the project that they use this line: `Crypt.Decrypt(encrypted, RandomCrypt.password)` to decrypt... how can i replicate this inside a PHP project ?

I know it's quite confusing but is there a way to use the functions of the CRYPTLib dll inside a PHP + APache system to decrypt strings that were encrypted with C# + IIS ?

Comment: Cannot find anything about ACECryptlib or RandomCrypt. As such, it will be very tricky to answer this question.